# How to use promise.all() to wait until a promise in an object is fully complete?

Tags: javascript

Review code below

```
const test = async (id) => {
  const result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(` ${id} finished`), 1000);
  });
  const output = {
    result,
  };

  return output;
};

async function output(ids) {
  const result = ids.map(async (id) => {
    return {
      id,
      result: test(id),
    };
  });
  const output = await Promise.all(result);
  console.log(output); // should output no promises in the object
  return output;
}

const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
output(ids);
```

The output is :

```
[
  { id: 1, result: Promise { <pending> } },
  { id: 2, result: Promise { <pending> } },
  { id: 3, result: Promise { <pending> } },
  { id: 4, result: Promise { <pending> } },
  { id: 5, result: Promise { <pending> } },
  { id: 6, result: Promise { <pending> } },
  { id: 7, result: Promise { <pending> } },
  { id: 8, result: Promise { <pending> } },
  { id: 9, result: Promise { <pending> } }
]
```

Is there any way to wait until the promise is fully complete ? I want the output result to not be a promise. Unsure if there is quick fix to this. I don't want to put `await test(id)`.

for example, { id: 1, result: "id1 is fully complete" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const result = ids.map(async (id) => {
  return {
    id,
    result: test(id),
  };
});
```

You're missing an `await` in here. test is going to return a promise, and you're assigning that promise to `result`, but instead you want to wait for the promise to resolve, and assign the value.

```
const result = ids.map(async (id) => {
  return {
    id,
    result: await test(id),
  };
});
```

You'll still be creating an array of promises (since async functions return promises), but now the promises resolve to objects that don't have promises inside them.

Comment: if .map() is async, then would performance be the same if I do `await test(id)` ? Because I want to run this command test() async for all?

Comment: `.map` steps through the entire array synchronously. You will start all 9 timers at time 0, and then they will all go off approximately 1 second later.

Comment: oh I thought there would be a performance decrease if I did await. Thanks for clarification. This is the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Items passed to `Promise.all` have to be promises, but you are passing object like `{ id: 1, result: Promise { <pending> } }`

### Solution

First pass promises to the `Promise.all`, then map them.

```js
const test = async (id) => {
  const result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(` ${id} finished`), 1000);
  });
  const output = {
    result,
  };

  return output;
};

async function output(ids) {
  const promises = ids.map(id => test(id))
  const resolved = await Promise.all(promises)
  const mapped = resolved.map((result, index) => ({
    ...result,
    id: ids[index]
  }))
  return mapped
}

const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
output(ids).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this while keeping the same object in one .map() call? (i.e. I don't want to re-add the index)

Comment: No that I know of

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing in a much clearer and shorter way:

```js
const test = async (id) =>(
 {id, 
  result:await new Promise(res =>setTimeout(() => res(` ${id} finished`), 1000))
 }
);
    
Promise.all([3,5,7,2,4,6].map(test)).then(console.log)
```